# Create a new list by appending prefix on each value of old list in python single line

Tags: python

```
a = ('A', 'B', 'C')

a = [(x, '#' + x) for x in a]
print(a)
```

Current Output:

```
[('A', '#A'), ('B', '#B'), ('C', '#C')]
```

Desired Output:

```
['A', '#A', 'B', '#B', 'C', '#C']
```

How can I do this with a one-liner, avoiding multi-line `for` loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
a = ('A', 'B', 'C')

result = [xi for x in a for xi in (x, '#' + x)]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['A', '#A', 'B', '#B', 'C', '#C']
```

Comment: `[x for x in a for x in (x, '#' + x)]` this is also gives same output, is there any particular reason you are using `xi` instead of `x`? I don't think so, outer `x` will be overwrite by inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested comprehensions:

```
a = ('A', 'B', 'C')

a = [y for x in a for y in (x, '#'+x)]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['A', '#A', 'B', '#B', 'C', '#C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
a = ('A', 'B', 'C')
result = []
for i in a:
    result.append(i)
    result.append(f'#{i}')

print(result)
```

Comment: OP is specifically looking for a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this are best solved by attempting to write out a set of `for` loops that have a single `append` and possibly a condition in them. I find it much easier to manipulate the fully expanded loop, and translating to comprehension is trivial if the format is right. For example, your current attempt looks something like this:

```
result = []
for x in a:
    result.append((x, '#' + x))
```

Instead of having pairs in the list, you are trying to do something like

```
result = []
for x in a:
    result.append(x)
    result.append('#' + x)
```

While this form does not lend itself to a one-line comprehension, we can get a hint from rephrasing it as

```
result = []
for x in a:
    result.extend((x, '#' + x))
```

Since this does exactly what you want, and `list.extend` is equivalent to a nested loop, you have your solution:

```
result = []
for x in a:
    for y in (x, '#' + x):
        result.append(y)
```

Converting this loop to a comprehension is almost as trivial as removing the colons and newlines, and putting some square brackets around it. Keep in mind that nested loops go into the comprehension in exactly the order that they appear when written out:

```
result = [y for for x in a for y in (x, '#' + x)]
```

The solution itself is pretty trivial, but hopefully this explanation will help you think about how to convert loops into comprehensions more independently in the 
future.